# How to pass value to uri template from android?

Tags: java, android, wcf, android-asynctask

Here am trying to pass json string from android using asynctask and httpurlconnection but when i try to pass the value it throws http 400 bad request how can i achieve this

```
             listobj = account_sf_db.list();
                String empty="yog";
                recyclerView.setAdapter(accountListAdapter);
                new Account_async().execute(acnt);
            int count = account_sf_db.getTaskCount();


          public class Account_async extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
                String JsonResponse = null;

                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                 HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

                    String JsonDATA = params[0];
                   byte[]post=JsonDATA.getBytes();
                  int request_post=post.length;
                    BufferedReader reader = null;
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL("http://xx.xx.x.xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/CreateAccount/"+JsonDATA);
                        Log.d("s",url.toString());
                        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(String.valueOf(Integer.toString(request_post)).getBytes()));
                        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream()));
                        out.write(params.toString());
                        out.close();
                        int response = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                        if (response >= 400 && response <= 499) {
                            Log.e("", "HTTPx Response: " + response + " - " + urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
                            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getErrorStream());

                        }

                        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                        if (inputStream == null) {
                            return null;
                        }
                        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                        String inputLine;
                        while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
                            buffer.append(inputLine + "\n");
                        if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                            // Stream was empty. No point in parsing.
                            return null;
                        }
                        JsonResponse = buffer.toString();
                        Log.i("Error", JsonResponse);
                        //send to post execute
                        return JsonResponse;


                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (urlConnection != null) {
                            urlConnection.disconnect();
                        }
                        if (reader != null) {
                            try {
                                reader.close();
                            } catch (final IOException e) {
                                Log.e("", "Error closing stream", e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }      
        }
```

Here it throws bad request when i try to pass json string dono where am making mistake even i tried using volley but it throws same error can someone helpme is this the only method to pass the json value here one more info am trying to parse the list using gson library don't know where am making mistake

Comment: Can you shrink your 200 lines of code to the relevant part?

Comment: Try [enabling tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025) on the WCF service, and it will tell you why it thinks that the request it received is bad.

Comment: i have shorten it @Marc